# How do I to split a single word in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good morning,

I've encountered a problem, albeit small but annoying, in VBA.

What I want to do is split up a given `String` and pass it into an array; this array will be an array of characters.

I'm aware of the `Split()` function; it splits a string based on a given delimiter - but this is best suited for strings that have actual delimiters - mine does not.

So, for example - say I receive the string `"123asdf4"` - how would I go about placing this into an array? So, from the above example - the array would look like this:

```
myArray(0) = 1
myArray(1) = 2
myArray(2) = 3
myArray(3) = a
myArray(4) = s
'You get the picture
```

Thanks

P.S. I can't recall what libraries you can import into VBA code - i.e. C, C++ or C# libraries. Can someone outline which it is?

Comment: what is wrong with loop in this situation?: `for i=1 to len(YourString)` and next you could use `Mid function`.

Comment: will investigate that now - thanks

Comment: @KazJaw mehow has posted an answer which I think sums up what you outlined above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SplitByCharacter()` function returns a String array data type. This array is made of characters that you passed to the function originally (`myStr` which was "123asdf4"). So now your `myArr` is an array with 8 string objects in it.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim myStr As String
    myStr = "123asdf4"

    Dim myArr
    myArr = SplitByCharacter(myStr)



    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        Debug.Print "pos: " & i, "val: " & myArr(i)
    Next i

End Sub


Private Function SplitByCharacter(s As String) As String()
    ReDim arr(Len(s) - 1) As String
    Dim i  As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        arr(i - 1) = Mid$(s, i, 1) ' or Right$(Left$(s, i), 1)
    Next i
    SplitByCharacter = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Good answer - it worked flawlessly though I'm still dissecting it at the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String, arr() As String

str = "123asdf4" 
ReDim arr(Len(str)-1)

For i = 0 to Len(str)-1
    arr(i) = mid$(str, i+1, 1)
Next i
```

Comment: I placed your code into a sub and received an "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" error. It occurred at the line where you assign values to the elements of the array.

Comment: it should say arr(i) = Mid$(str, i + 1, 1)